# Best practice sync MongoDB and API data

Tags: database, mongodb, api, synchronization

The ERP used in the company that I work for has some information available across API requests. Currently my code just grab each document and replace at Mongo. It does not handle excluded documents, for example. Moreover, this code takes hours to get all information because API requests are limited.
Is there a tool, library, app, etc. that can sync these databases?
What is the best practice to achieve the synchronization of API and MongoDB database?

PS: why do I need to sync them? API requests are limited.
PS2: not all, but some API requests return "last edited" timestamp. I am using it to reduce running time.

Comment: Same problem here...